# DHCP of LXC on Proxmox doens't work

Tags: dhcp, lxc, proxmox

I give up, for days I have trying to figure it out. So any help will be very welcome.

I have a Proxmox virtualization server and everything works fine, except that none LXC (Linux Container) can get an answer from the DHCP server.
I have the following:

- LXC + DHCP client = **No**
- LXC + static IP = Yes
- VM + DHCP client = Yes
- VM + static IP = Yes

Therefore I know it isn't a firewall or networking issue.
My best guess it is a kernel issue, but again I have another Proxmox server on the same network (and same Proxmox cluster) that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the fuss.

I am not sure yet how it happened or where it was happening, but the problem was solved once I changed the MAC address of the Linux container.

And since I didn't keep the old address, I can't replicate the problem. But I can assume the problem was on the network layer 2/some arp table.

Thank you all anyway.